# Unity3D for Android and iOS: QR-Code Decoding (Reader)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, qr-code, zxing

Is there a good QR Decoding Script or Pluging for Unity3D (Android and iOS)?

Or has someone already successfully integrated ZXing in Unity3D for Android and iOS? [Here](http://ydaira.blogspot.de/2012/05/how-to-decode-qr-code-using-unity3d.html) is a good solution for Webcam, but WebCamTexture does not always work on [Android](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/123732-Webcam-on-Android-not-working) :(

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a non-Free ($50) plugin available: [Antares QR Code](http://u3d.as/content/neo-pax/antares-qr-code/1QF)

If you're not interested in paying for a plugin then you'll have to create your own. Since ZXing is available for both iOS and Android you can create C# wrappers for it and then use a native plugin on iOS and the C#-to-Java extensions on Android to get what you need.

Comment: Native Plugin is not available for Android or iOS Basic. Right?

Antares QR Code can not read from the video stream. Can I take a picture with Unity at runtime and decoding with Antares? Is there an example? Unfortunately, there is no demo for Antares.

Comment: According to the license comparison page http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses Native Code Plugins Support is available for Android and iOS basic.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I read wrong. 

Can I take a picture with Unity at runtime and decoding with Antares? Is there an example? Unfortunately, there is no demo for Antares.

Comment: @Oli I haven't used Antares QR Code myself, so I don't know. You should ask the company directly: http://antares-universe.com/

Comment: Ok, have you an example for an C# Wrapper and a C#-to-Java extension. What do you mean exactly? Can I do it all directly in Unity? 

Can I call it then just like in Android?

Intent intent = new Intent(this,   com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
  intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
  String name = "SCAN_MODE";
  String value = "QR_CODE_MODE"; // Product_MODE
  intent.putExtra(name, value);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: There are samples on the Unity site. Check out http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html and http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html It takes a bit of work.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an other plugin available for barcodes and QRCode for both Android and iOS : [Easy Code Scanner](http://u3d.as/content/c4mprod/easy-code-scanner/3sM)

You just have to call a single method (common C# API for Android and iPhone) and it automatically launches a camera view/preview that decodes the barcode/QR code and gives you back the literal string of it in a callback. It is based on ZBar and you have nothing to integrate, everything is already self packaged.

The plugin can give you back the picture taken during the preview (as a Texture2D/Image) and also decode directly in the scripts a Texture2D/image without camera preview/shot.

Answer (score 1):

The blog that the OP linked to, now has a free option for Android devices [here](http://ydaira.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-decode-qr-codes-using-unity3d.html) You can also check out this related video
[ARCamera prefab in Unity Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-v0OJdqxFpo) 
You may need to fix some minor compile errors to get everything working due to newer versions of Vuforia having different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use free [metaio SDK](http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/) which has built in support for QR codes reading.